# Serialization unit test for Hazelcast's DataSerializable writeData and readData

Tags: serialization, deserialization, hazelcast

Given I have `Audit` class:

```
public class Audit implements DataSerializable {

    private String createdBy = "me";
    private LocalDateTime createdTimestamp = LocalDateTime.now();

    private String modifiedBy;
    private LocalDateTime modifiedTimestamp;

    @Override
    public void writeData(ObjectDataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeUTF(getCreatedBy());
        out.writeObject(getCreatedTimestamp());

        out.writeUTF(getModifiedBy());
        out.writeObject(getModifiedTimestamp());
    }

    @Override
    public void readData(ObjectDataInput in) throws IOException {
        setCreatedBy(in.readUTF());
        setCreatedTimestamp(in.readObject());

        setModifiedBy(in.readUTF());
        setModifiedTimestamp(in.readObject());
    }

}
```

I'd like to write unit test which tests serialization and deserialization.

Implementations of `ObjectDataOutput` and `ObjectDataInput` are either package private or they require to provide components from Hazelcast API.

How can I create such test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can clone the object using `SerializationService` and test equality

```
SerializationService serializationService = new DefaultSerializationServiceBuilder().build();

Audit expected = new Audit(...);
Audit actual = serializationService.toObject(serializationService.toData(expected);
assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

Answer (score 0):

After all, it is possible to create such test.
I was missing `DefaultSerializationServiceBuilder` which can create `SerializationService`

The whole test written in Groovy is:

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals

import java.time.LocalDateTime

import com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DefaultSerializationServiceBuilder
import com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ObjectDataInputStream
import com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ObjectDataOutputStream
import com.hazelcast.spi.serialization.SerializationService
import org.junit.Test

class AuditTest {

    @Test
    void "serialize and deserialize Audit"() {
        def toSerialize = new Audit(createdBy: "me",
                createdTimestamp: LocalDateTime.now(),
                modifiedBy: "you",
                modifiedTimestamp: LocalDateTime.now(),
        )
        SerializationService serializationService = new DefaultSerializationServiceBuilder().build()

        def outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        def dataOutput = new ObjectDataOutputStream(outputStream, serializationService)
        toSerialize.writeData(dataOutput)

        def inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray())
        def dataInput = new ObjectDataInputStream(inputStream, serializationService)

        def toDeserialize = new Audited()
        toDeserialize.readData(dataInput)

        assert reflectionEquals(toDeserialize, toSerialize)
    }
}
```

Comment: you can maybe serialize and de-serialize the object and check the equality ? 

`Data data = serializationService.toData(audit)` 
and
`Audit clone = serializationService.toObject(data)`

Comment: @ali Thanks for the tip. Test can get even shorter with the use of `SerializationService` API.